# Trouble with Regex backreference in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm playing around with group backreferences in Python's Regex to try to understand them and I'm not having much luck.

```
import re

leftQuotes = re.compile("((\"|\“)([\w|\d]))")
rightQuotes = re.compile("(([\w|\d])(\"|\”))")

s = "This is “problematic”"

s = re.sub(leftQuotes, r'‘\3', s)
s = re.sub(rightQuotes, r'’\3', s)

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
This is ‘problemati’”
```

In the first `re.sub()`, I managed to successfully replace the left double quotation mark with a single left quotation mark while keeping the matching character (in this case, a "p"). But the right side doesn't behave in the same way, regardless of the group backreference (1, 2, 3).

**Results of backreferences:**

```
\1: ‘problemati’c” 
\2: ‘problemati’c 
\3: ‘problemati’”
```

Comment: You overcaptured it. Use `s = re.sub(rightQuotes, r'\2’', s)`, or better just remove unnecessary groups to only keep one that you need to keep, then just use Group 1 backreference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That gives me `This is ‘problemati’c`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As I'd said originally in the post, all backreferences resulted in undesirable output. \1 gets `This is ‘problemati’c”`

Comment: As I said, you overcapture it, see https://ideone.com/rjLs4N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code, replace the second `sub` with:

```
s = re.sub(rightQuotes, r'\2’', s)
```

should work, since the word character in the second pattern comes as the second capture group and it should come before the single quote replacement as well.

---

Besides, you don't really need capture groups here, use *look around* would be cleaner, (though not critical quoting the string with single quote can save you some typing as @CasimiretHippolyte's comment):

```
import re
​
leftQuotes = re.compile('(?:"|“)(?=\w)')
rightQuotes = re.compile('(?<=\w)(?:"|”)')
​
s = "This is “problematic”"
​
s = re.sub(leftQuotes, r'‘', s)
s = re.sub(rightQuotes, r'’', s)
​
s
# 'This is ‘problematic’'
```

Also since `\w` includes `\d`, `[\w|\d]` can be replaced by `\w`.

Comment: Instead of a lookahead or a lookbehind, it's more simple to use a word boundary.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good call.

Comment: I meant something like : `(?:"|“)\b` and `\b(?:"|“)`